# matching tables name with show tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all tables name from a database.

In my DB I have tables like:

```
_table1,
_table2,
table3,
table4,
table5_xrefs
```

but I want to get only the tables without _ at the beginning and without _xref at the end.
So in this example I need only table3 and table4.

I'm using `show tables` to show all tables name and after I'm using PHP to match the correct table name. I was wondering if I could do the same using only a MySQL query.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It's possible but you have to know that column name returned from `SHOW TABLES` query is concatenation of string `tables_in_` and your database name. So it would look like this, for database `test`:

```
SHOW TABLES 
      WHERE tables_in_test NOT LIKE '\_%' 
        AND tables_in_test NOT LIKE '%\_xrefs'
```

But I would prefer to use `information_schema` database to get this info:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA() /* = 'test'*/
   AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '\_%'
   AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%\_xrefs'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I realized that the first query is faster than the second one? Why do you prefer to use that one?

Comment: Mainly for consistency, I'm using information_schema to get many more info about tables and fields in my applications. Second reason is that I dislike having variable in column names - it can not be  easily put into stored procedure.

Comment: Easiest method 
show tables like '%table%'

Answer (score 5):

You can [use LIKE or WHERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) in SHOW TABLES queries.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I can use 'like' but I can't use 'not like' or I'm wrong

Comment: e.g. `show tables like "%mail%";` for those who came here for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Best way to find the tables with databases

```
SELECT table_schema as database_name, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND table_name like 'users%'
ORDER BY table_schema, table_name;
```