# Search Specific Range of Tables mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question that is plaguing me.  I have a mysql database that is being used for historical data.  Basically every year the system writes a new table in the database housing the time data.

so it is like this:

tables:
year_2017
year_2018
year_2019

and in each table there is data.

What I would like to do is build a query that will search through these specific tables.

Now there are other tables in there I don't want to search through.  I only want the year_* tables.

Basically I would want SELECT * FROM year_*

I know you could do SELECT * FROM year_2017, year_2018, year_2019 but the problem is that every year there is going to be a new table so I would have to edit the query every year and I don't want to do that.

Any help would be great.

Comment: A note: this functionality could also be accomplished by having one `year` table that is [horizontally partitioned](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-overview.html) by the year. This approach would simplify your query and eliminate the problem of maintaining a list of tables (or explicitly querying your schema).

Comment: For explicitly querying the database schema to find a list of tables, see this possible dupe target: [matching tables name with show tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432062/matching-tables-name-with-show-tables).

Comment: you have to union the year tables, but they have to exist, a loo in a stired procedure plus PREPARED STATEMENTS will do the trick

Comment: How the query would look like? Is it going to be a `UNION` query? Or is it going to be a (LEFT) JOIN between a reference table to all of those `year_xx` tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `information_schema.tables`, find the names of the tables that contain the `year_` and then place the table names in a temporary table. Then fetch each table with a data loop.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp(
      tablename varchar(100)
    );

    INSERT INTO temp
    SELECT t.TABLE_NAME
    FROM information_schema.tables t
    WHERE t.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%year_%';
    
    
    WHILE (Select Count(*) From temp) > 0 DO
      SET @tablename= (Select tablename From temp limit 1);
      SET @sql= concat("select * from ", @tablename);
      prepare exec from @sql;
      execute exec;  
      Delete From temp Where tablename=@tablename;
    END WHILE;
END;
 
CALL  myproc();
```

demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df40e55f1d6ff4ae639676c6c138356f)

Comment: This is great but I keep getting syntax errors.  I am using MySQL 5.7

Comment: result in mysql 5.7 db<>fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f1c2a288c35bc46f5c49dc892d69dfec

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to store the table name. But you'd need to come up with an automation to fill the table name variables.
[mysql prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

```
/* MYSQL */
SET @table = 't1';
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table);
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt3;
```

Comment: exec doesn't exist in mysql

Comment: The sql tag is ambiguous. Many people (including you, apparently) think it means "Microsoft SQL Server." But the preferable tag to refer to that product on Stack Overflow is [tag:sql-server]. The tag 'sql' just means the SQL language, which is an ANSI/ISO standard, and that tag does not refer to any particular product that implements the SQL language. If you mouse over the sql tag on the question above, you'll see a description and guidance for usage.

Comment: @steveo314 no i don't think so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax